# How to capture desktop using ffmpeg? getting error when stop recording: System.InvalidOperationException: 'StandardIn has not been redirected.'

Tags: c#, winforms, ffmpeg

I want it to record the entire desktop then when stopping to save the file to the hard drive. and to hide without the console window of the ffmpeg.

but getting this exception error. and i'm setting the RedirectStandardInput to true.
so i'm not sure why it's showing this error.

The exception error is on the line

```
process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(qKey, 0, 1);
```

The full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace Desktop_Recorder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Process process;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            process = new Process();
            Start(@"d:\test.mp4", 30);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Stop();
        }

        public void Start(string FileName, int Framerate)
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"d:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe"; // Change the directory where ffmpeg.exe is.  
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\"; // The output directory  
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-y -f gdigrab -framerate " + Framerate +
                " -i desktop -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p " + FileName;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; //Redirect stdin
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);  //Wait 3 seconds (for testing).
            Stop();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            byte[] qKey = Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk").GetBytes("q"); //Get encoding of 'q' key
            process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(qKey, 0, 1); //Write 'q' key to stdin of FFmpeg sub-processs
            process.StandardInput.BaseStream.Flush(); //Flush stdin (just in case).
            process.Close();
        }


        private void btnStartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it some reason to use `StandardInput.BaseStream` intead of just `StandardInput`?

Comment: @Serg changing the line to process.StandardInput.Write(qKey, 0, 1); give me error on the qKey Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'char[]'

Comment: `StandardInput` is a StreamWriter, you can have `process.StandardInput.Write("q")`. It's also set to auto-flush by default